# How to speed up respond of image processing result from camera when using firebase_ml_vision of flutter package

Tags: flutter, dart, face-detection, firebase-machine-learning

I am using a package flutter of firebase_ml_vision. Is there a way to get fast respond of result from face detection? Here is the part of the code

```
final faceDetector = FirebaseVision.instance.faceDetector(
            FaceDetectorOptions(
                mode: FaceDetectorMode.fast,
                enableLandmarks: true,
                enableClassification: false,
                enableContours: false,
                enableTracking: false));
        List<Face> faces = await faceDetector.processImage(image);
```

and I have changed FaceDetectorMode from accurate to fast, but I still get a slow response.

Comment: do you want livemode? link  : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_camera_ml_vision

Comment: hi thank you, what's the difference between flutter_camera_ml_vision and firebase_ml_vision... I read your link and it has the same feature like ```FirebaseVision.instance.faceDetector().processImage```

Comment: firebase_ml_vision is only image ( file and take photo and etc. ) so,  flutter_camera_ml_vision is using flutter camera controller. and live checking face and barcode detect